# Не отображаются картинки в медиa Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Перенес сайт вместе с базой, и тут обнаружил, что в библиотеке не отображаются картинки, путь только такой `/wp-includes/images/media/default.png`, при клике на саму картинку показывает правильную урлу. И ни ошибок, ничего. Помогите разобраться. Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 90% за то, что ссылки внутри базы не правили. Вот и результат.

Comment: добавил, скриншот, сам урл правильный, если его скопировать и вставить в поисковник то отобразиться картинка

Comment: Почему в поисковик, в не в адресную строку браузера?

Comment: я имел ввиду адресную строку браузера

Comment: А на сайте отображаются?

Comment: нет, пишет "<img scr='(unknown)'>"

Comment: База кривая. Переносите заново плагином duplicator

Comment: Так тот сайт с которого скопирована база все работает.

Comment: Базу НАДО ПРАВИТЬ при переносе  сайта. Вы с базой какие действия делали?

Comment: Сразу после переноса такие битые картинки стали, потом начал пути правильные подставлять для картинок и название сайта поменял везде, больше ничего не делал.

Comment: Переносить нужно с пом https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/ тогда не только этих проблем можно избежать

Comment: Ида. Небось ещё и название файлов по-русски?

Comment: нет название на англ

Comment: так как у нас мультисайты на одном домене и у многих сайтов есть свои айдишники, бось плагином это не получиться сделать (я прро перезалить базу)

Comment: Надо не бояться, а пробовать - все получится. Если не плагином, то srdb.

Comment: Дубликатор с мультисайтом работает только в платной версии. Но есть др плагины для мигрирования. Или же скрипт https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/.  И первое что менять - это пути к файлам. Домен после.

Comment: @SeVlad да я знаю, что только в платной, но там можно по одному сайту перегонять (тоже криво, понимаю). Да, есть и другие, поиск duplicator multisite. А про srdb я в ответе написал.

Answer (score 1):

Причина в том, что сайт перенесен неправильно. WordPress содержит все внутренние ссылки в базе как абсолютные, включая название домена: `http://my-site.org/wp-content/uploads/...`. Причем эти ссылки могут быть как в обычном текстовом виде, так и внутри сериализованных переменных. Правка файла .sql "руками" - прямой путь к полному разрушению сайта.

Пользуйтесь специальными средствами для переноса сайтов, например, плагином [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/). Он работает с мультисайтом только в платной версии.

Есть бесплатные плагины для переноса мультисайтов, например [MultiSite Clone Duplicator](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-clone-duplicator/#description).

Или можно воспользоваться средством массовых правок базы, под названием [Database Search and Replace Script](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/).

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Я решил данный вопрос так:
1) Эспортировал файл медиа (xml) со старого сайта с админки;
2) Импортировал на новый сайт.

В моем случае это сработало!

Спасибо всем, кто пытался мне помочь.