# Где поле на картинку в БД? Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Переносил сайт с одного на другой, все ок. Но обнаружил, что после переноса не прикрепились картинки к постам (атачу скрин).
Подскажите, где вообще хранится информация в БД, когда картинка прикреплена к посту?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну неправильнож перенёс. уже ж говорили как надо https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/712400/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8a-wordpress А "где хранится" - не поможет.

Answer (score 0):

ID находится в таблице wp_postmeta с meta_key под названием _thumbnail_id

Ссылка на картинку находится в таблице wp_posts с post_type под названием attachment.

Comment: все заработало тогда. Перезалил в базе wp_posts